# Что быстрее словарь, список или массив для арифметических операций?

Tags: python, массивы, списки, словари

Ну вроде ясно что массив быстрее списка. Однако то что словарь оказывается медленнее - непонятно. Ведь поиск в словаре как никак самый быстрый?
Неужели запись в список быстрее записи в словарь?
Я имею ввиду - словарь это dict(), список - это list(), а  массив это array, но не из numpy.

конкретный код если кому интересно

```
 def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
     wrk_d = {i:0 for i in range(n+1)}
     for a,b,k in queries:
         wrk_d[a-1] += k
         wrk_d[min(b,n)] -= k
     max_, _ = 0, 0
     for v in wrk_d.values():
         if v!=0:
             _ += v
             if max_<_ :
                 max_ = _
     return max_
```

и его близнец:

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    wrk_d = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
    for a,b,k in queries:
        wrk_d[a-1] += k
        wrk_d[min(b,n)] -= k
    max_, _ = 0, 0
    for v in wrk_d:
        if v!=0:
            _ += v
            if max_<_ :
                max_ = _
    return max_
```

размер списка/словаря n=10000000,
len(queries) == 100000
время для списка: 1.788 секунды
время для словаря:2.617 секунды
время для массива:2.257 секунды....

```
from array import array
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    wrk_d = array('l', [0 for i in range(n+1)])
    for a,b,k in queries:
        wrk_d[a-1] += k
        wrk_d[min(b,n)] -= k
    max_, _ = 0, 0
    for v in wrk_d:
        if v!=0:
            _ += v
            if max_<_ :
                max_ = _
    return max_

 [![страница из книги Ромальо Лучиано][1]][1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что конкретно вы имеете в виду, говоря массив и список?

Comment: «массив это array, но не из numpy» — а откуда?

Comment: @andreymal array из стандартной библиотеки Python:    https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array
 Оказалось что простое прибавление константы в цикле по срезам словаря оказалось почти в 2 раза медленнее чем то же по спискам. При этом  количество элементов не менялось. Выходит словарь годится только для хранения-чтения?

Comment: Для каждого конкретного случая любой из примеров может оказаться быстрей, нужно понимать как они устроены и использовать наиболее подходящий под ваши нужды... Если в отрыве от конкретного ЯП и в качестве примера - вставка в массив очень дорогая операция, в отличии от списка.. А например поиск в словаре гораздо быстрей поиска в массиве или в списке... Зато обработка массива как матрицы будет быстрей чем списка\словаря... переход к i элементу списка - дороже такового же перехода в массиве...

Comment: «словарь оказывается медленнее» — а в каких конкретно задачах-то? Запись у словаря будет медленнее (почти) всегда, потому что надо посчитать хэш и аккуратно всё в память по индексам положить, а в list() (чтоб добавить элемент в конец) достаточно тупо несколько байт записать в заранее выделенную память (а вот если заранее выделенной памяти нет, то может затупить на realloc)

Comment: @andreymal Не знаю кому это адресовано но запись в массив будет медленней в случае если запись ведется в начало\середину(вставка) массива или массив невозможно увеличить в данном месте памяти(пересоздание массива с увеличением размера и копированием содержимого), но опять таки для массива длинной в 2-3 элемента даже этот пример будет быстрей чем вставка в словарь

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, забыл упомянуть, что я имею в виду добавление нового элемента в конец (если запасная память есть, то это должно быть очень быстро). Но вообще автору нужно свою задачу расписать, а то мы тут гадаем

Comment: Да даже гадать не нужно, автору нужно понять внутренне строение и всё станет на свои места, `а в list() ` простите, но в питоне разве лист на массивах выполнен? я почему то считал что это одно\дву направленные списки...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков как это ни удивительно, list() в питоне является массивом, не знаю почему

Comment: Для автора вопроса, ваш код всегда будет быстрей выполнятся для массива. Список - нужен для многократной вставки и последующего перебора по порядку, Словарь для поиска. @andreymal Спасибо за пояснение по спискам, тогда теряется их основной смысл и плюсов по сравнению с массивом - мало.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86188/discussion-between---and-andreymal).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я знаю, что список словарь и массив в пайтоне разные структуры. Меня удивляет что для такой задачи список оказался быстрее словаря.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, было бы проще найти оптимальный подход если бы вы объяснили что вы пытаетесь сделать и привели небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных...

Comment: @MaxU - Благодарю. Действительно приятно от вас слышать такое предложение. Однако все что я хочу  -  понять, почему список оказался быстрее массива. Так сказать "на будущее".
Просто неправильно понял свойства словарей когда читал Дучано Рамальо...
Хорошего вечера!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, для начала стоит сделать профайлинг, чтобы понять какой блок занимает больше всего времени